# can jstack dump specific thread stack on linux

Tags: java, jvm, jstack

can hotspots' jstack command dump only a specified thread's stack?

jstack $pid will dump all threads' stack on linux. can it dump only specified stack if the $pid is thread id?

Comment: In case you named the threads when starting up your application, you can always search the thread dump with your thread's name.

Comment: yes, it's a good way...